# Apex REST with oAuth JSON Web Tokens

Tags: oauth, oracle-apex, jwt, oracle-apex-5

I wonder how to create a template in the apex for jwt auth but I can not see a way to do it in PL/SQL, someone help me?

Comment: can you give more details about your need. do you want to consume a json web service in apex which needs oauth atuhentication or do you want to use oauth service of apex for validating third party applications while they are accessing the rest services in apex

Comment: @Bahadirs I want to use oauth service of apex for validating third party applications while they are accessing the rest services in apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name of this service changed to ORACLE REST Data Services
you can check it is documentation in oracle site from below link
i think sections after the `Accessing the RESTful Services from a Third Party Application` would meet your needs

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html#accessing_the_restful_services_from_a_third_party_application

Answer (score 1):

You can use RSA signed JWT tokens with the commercial [OraRSA package](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-rsa/tutorial/jwt-apex-web-service/). Sample usage is:

```
  l_payload_data := '{
         "sub": "1234567890",
         "name": "John Doe",
         "admin": true
        }';
 
  l_jwt := ORA_RSA.JWT_SIGN(l_payload_data, 
                UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(l_private_key), 
                ORA_RSA.HASH_SHA256);

  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Authorization';
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := l_jwt;
```

For HMAC signed JWT tokens I can recommend you the [JWT_NINJA package](https://github.com/morten-egan/jwt_ninja/)